# joomla 3.1.1 editor stripping html code

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I disabled all editor plugins in plugin manager and now when I want to edit a html module a simple editor appears which only shows html code. after editing the code when I press the save button then html code changes somehow \" inserted to my code.

in global configuration => text filtering => no filtering is selected for super user and administrator.

how can I disable joomla editor from stripping my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Joomla back-end, then **System > System Information > PHP Information** and check if `magic_quotes_gpc` parameter is enabled in your PHP configuration. If yes, you need to disable it as Joomla recommends to turn it off.

Comment: Hi, this is just a guess from my own experience, please try it and tell me if it worked.

Comment: I turned it off and problem solved. You really saved me, thanks

Comment: Yeah that happened to me before, happy i could help :)